# Cant find methods in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have the node js code like this:

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/', function(request, response){
  console.log(request.body);      // your JSON
  response.send(request.body);    // echo the result back
});

app.listen(3000);
```

when I run I get the error like this:

```
  , app = express.createServer();
                  ^
TypeError: Object function createApplication() {
  var app = function(req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  };

  mixin(app, proto);
  mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype);

  app.request = { __proto__: req, app: app };
  app.response = { __proto__: res, app: app };
  app.init();
  return app;
} has no method 'createServer'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/anto_belgin/programs/node/appleconnect.js:2:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

I have installed `express` using:

```
npm install express
```

Is there anything I need to do get it working?

Comment: Note: `express.createServer()` was [deprecated with 3.x](https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x#changed) and [removed with 4.x](https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x#expresscreateserver).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my express 4 app, I'm doing this:

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express(); 
var server = app.listen(8081, function() {});
```

Since express changed a bit from v3 to v4, make sure you're looking at instructions for the version you are running.

I think `createServer()` is something you do on the `http` module, whereas express runs at a higher level on top of that so if you're starting a server using the express module, you do it differently.

From the Express documentation, `app.listen()` is a convenience method that replaces this:

```
app.listen = function(){
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

Comment: I just learned express myself and found it difficult to sort out which version random articles on the web were written for.  I'm now doing the same thing with the socket.io library which also has two very different versions out there.  It's easy to get tripped up by this.